# How to find a function to which given power series converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to find a function to which given power series converges

Given Q :$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} n x^{2n-2} $$

by writing some terms I get $1−2x^2+3x^4−x^4$ if I take $x^2=y$ then I get $1−2y+3y^2−4y^3$ this is series for $(1+y)−2$. So replacing $y$ by $x^2$ will give me function. right ? –

I know about how to find R but have no idea about this question.Any help will be appreciated

Comment: If we are trying to "recognize" the power series, it sometimes helps to rewrite the terms in a way that simplifies the appearance.  It's a bit of an art, but have you tried to rearrange these terms?

Comment: by writing some terms i get $1 - 2x^{2} + 3x^{4} - x^{4} ... if i take x^2 = y ..then i get 1 -2y +3y^2 -4y^{3}... this is series for (1 + y)^ {-2}$.so replacing y by x^2  will give me function . right ?

Comment: You have a good idea, replacing $x^2$ by $y$.  The other thing to notice is that the factor $n$ in each term looks like someone took.... the what?

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}nx^{2n-2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(-x^2)^{n-1}$$

$$=\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-x^2)^n$$

Now $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-x^2)^n$ converges if $|-x^2|<1\iff -1<-x^2<1\iff1>x^2>-1$

If $x$ is real, $x^2\ge0>-1,$ we need $x^2<1\iff-1<x<1$

Comment: thanks sir . can you please explain concept behind this

Comment: @SophieClad, See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Infinite_geometric_series

Comment: ok so now i have to use formula for sum of infinite geometric progression and differentiate the answer right ?

Comment: @SophieClad, You can use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test as well

Comment: ratio test for what here sir ?

Comment: @SophieClad, For Converge , what else

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: It is my impression that the Question as originally framed saying it is known how to "find R" means that the radius of convergence was already found.  Rewriting the series as you did in the first line or two seems to be the sort of thing that was sought.

Comment: @hardmath, The user seems to be satisfied with the answer, not sure about the down vote :)

Comment: I don't know anything about a downvote, just trying to highlight the interpretation I made of the User's question!

Comment: @hardmath, Thanks for your feedback. Yes, the last two lines could be redundant

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Qustion Was not about Domain of x for convergence of power series,What i think, We need to find the sum of the power series ,which is a function of x